# Dynamically setting an Image on a ImageButton

Tags: android

I looked around but didn't find an answer to my problem anywhere. I have an imageButton, and would like to change the image when the button is pressed. I'm trying to figure out a way to get Eclipse to interpret my code literally.

```
String card = nextcard.toString();   //Becomes "Ace_Of_Hearts", for example
theImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.card);  //R.drawable.Ace_Of_Hearts is an image in the correct folder
```

Sadly this doesn't work. But because the card variable changes dynamically, I can't hard code a specific image to set the button to. So how should I set the image?

Comment: Better to elaborate More in details...

Comment: inside `if-else` condition change that image

Comment: I have an ImageButton, and all I want to know is how to set an image to that imageButton. The other answers on this site are insufficient, because they recommend something along the lines of "setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE)", which doesn't work if you're not hard-coding.

Comment: Didnt understand the negative votes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the id of all the cards in the drawable dir:

```
Integer ace_of_hearts_id = R.drawable.ace_of_hearts;
Integer ace_of_spades_id = R.drawable.ace_of_spades;
Integer queen_of_hearts_id = R.drawable.queen_of_hearts;
Integer ten_of_hearts_id = R.drawable.ten_of_hearts;
....
```

Put the ids and the string names in a HashMap as key value pairs:

```
    HashMap cardMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    cardMap.put("ace_of_hearts",ace_of_hearts_id);
    cardMap.put("ace_of_spades" ace_of_spades_id);    
......
```

Then add your code:

```
String card = nextcard.toString();   //Becomes "Ace_Of_Hearts", for example
theImageButton.setImageResource(cardMap.get(card));  /
```

Havent actually compiled the code, so there might be errors, but this should give you a basic idea to go about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagebutton selector for doing this.
First create selector in res/drawable btn_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>
```

Now you can use this selctor as src of your image button.

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:src="@drawable/btn_selector"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"/>
```